# How to create multiple children objects after the parent has been created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord, nested-attributes

This is my scenario:

I have a an **Order** model and a **Item** model. They have the following relationship:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :items
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :order
end
```

In my project, initially, I need to create the Order without Items. After that I need to create the items related to that order.

I have already tried user **nested_attributes**, however, I'm gonna need to created items more than once and in the second time try the Items I have already created shows up in the form for editing.

Any suggestions on the best approach?

EDIT:

Add one more info. I need the option to create multiple items at once.

Comment: Tried this: https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form?

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to create first your Order, and then the items.

```
# config/routes
...
resources :orders do
  resources :items
end

# app/controllers/itesm_controller.rb
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    order = Order.find(params[:order_id]
    @item = order.items.new
  end

  def create
    item.create(item_params)
    redirect_to orders_path # just guessing your paths
  end

  protected

  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:your, :attributes, :here)
  end
end

# Assuming Rails +5.1
# app/views/items/_form.html.erb
# you can use this partial in 'new.html.erb' and 'edit.html.erb'

<%= form_view model: @item do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :your_attribute %>
  <%= form.text_field :your_attribute %>
  <%= form.submit %>
```